# Replace non-numeric column values to float using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all non-number values from a specific column using pandas:

[image]

(a) I want to change all the last column values to float. There are some non-zero numeric values in the column that I want to preserve as floats.

(b) If non-numeric values exist, I want to replace them all to 0.0 (float). For example, in line 247, the last column has "a", I would like to change it to 0.0.

I have tried:

```py
def isnumber(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = df[clean_up.applymap(isnumber)]
```

This however changes every column:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should read your csv file with `header=None`, `skipinitialspace=True` and `quoting=1` as arguments of `read_csv` because your header looks like a normal row, you have space after each field separator and you have some values enclosed by double quotes.

To convert your last column, use `pd.numeric`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tubedata.csv', header=None, quoting=1, skipinitialspace=True)
df[5] = pd.to_numeric(df[5], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
# Before conversion
>>> df[5].unique()
array(['0', '3', '2', '4', '6', 'a'], dtype=object)

# After conversion
>>> df[5].unique()
array([0., 3., 2., 4., 6.])
```

Comment: Please share your csv file (or a sample), it will be simpler

Comment: because it needs iloc[:, -1] not iloc[-1]

Comment: @MugheesAsif. Thanks to accepted my answer. Next time share your data sooner, it will be easier for everyone

Comment: Is it possible to do this to the entire dataframe?

Comment: @HirakSarkar. `df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `pd.to_numeric` to every column by mapping it over the `DataFrame`. Using `errors='coerce'` turns columns that cannot be converted to `NaN` so they can be easily dropped in the following step:

```py
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna(axis=1)
```

To allow for bad values (such as `"a"`) within columns that are otherwise numeric, use `fillna` instead:

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['some column'], errors='coerce').fillna(0.0)
```

Comment: This changes the full dataframe to one column? I only want to change the last column

Comment: I do not want to drop any columns, I am only interested in changing the last column to (a) all float, and (b) all non-numeric values to 0.0.